# Ember reload, rerender component template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a template in which I have table. I am creating a component to contain table and filter criteria. Whenever there's filter criteria change I need to update the table. For that I want to rerender the table from component action whenever the component action is invoked.

How to rerender/refresh the component from
 its action?

Comment: EmberJS encourages *data down, actions up* approach. This means that as soon as your model changes, the underlying component should update the view. It would help us to see what you're code looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is automatically done in ember. Whenever there is a change in data it will automatically render. The problem I had was with the tag, which did not have hook for attribute change.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have this component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {get} = Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    filter: '',
    data: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
    filteredData: Ember.computed('filter', 'data', {
        get() {
            const filter = get(this, 'filter');
            return get(this, 'data').filter(item = item.indexOf(filer) > 0);
        }
    }),
})
```

then you can just use this in your template:

```
{{#each filteredData as |item|}}
    {{item}}
{{/each}}
```

whenever you change the `filter` property this will automatically update.